# Codility - Counting Elements Lessons : fastest algorithm swap

Tags: java, algorithm

i am [studying Codility chapter 2 : Counting elements](https://codility.com/media/train/2-CountingElements.pdf).

I tried to make the exercise, and i think I have a good solution O(n). is It a valid solution ?
Is it a better solution that the BEST solution proposed in te lesson ?

**Problem:** You are given an integer m (1  m  1 000 000) and two non-empty, zero-indexed arrays A and B of n integers, a0,a1,...,an−1 and b0,b1,...,bn−1 respectively (0  ai,bi  m). The goal is to check whether there is a swap operation which can be performed on these arrays in such a way that the sum of elements in array A equals the sum of elements in array B after the swap. By swap operation we mean picking one element from array A and
one element from array B and exchanging them.

**I tested my solution with these values :**
     int a[] = {2, 7, 12, 16};
     int b[] = {4, 8, 9};
     m = 16;

**note:** I commented the return to see the swapped values.

```
 public int resultat(int[] A, int B[], int max) {

    int sumA = Arrays.stream(A).sum();
    int sumB = Arrays.stream(B).sum();

    int[] countA = count(A, max);
    int[] countB = count(B, max);
    int diff = sumA - sumB;
    int diffMin = 0;

    if (diff % 2 != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    diffMin = diff / 2;
    if (sumA > sumB) {

        if (diff < countA.length && diffMin < countB.length && countA[diff] != 0 && countB[diffMin] != 0) {
            System.out.println("A:" + diff + "- B:" + diffMin);
            //return 1;
        }
    } else {

        if (diffMin < countA.length && diff < countB.length && countB[diff] != 0 && countA[diffMin] != 0) {
            System.out.println("A:" + diffMin + "- B:" + diff);
            //return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}

public int[] count(int[] X, int max) {
    int[] p = new int[max + 1];
    Arrays.fill(p, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        p[X[i]] += 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: *I tested my solution with these values*. How did you test it, did you use any testing framework that java programmers use frequently?

Comment: I didn't use any testing framework java for this case. I created a class with the values I wanted. I know Junit, I am going to try with It. do you advice me a better framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your solution is `O(n + m)`, because of `count(A, max)` and `count(B, max)` invocations. `count()` is linear.
2. It's not valid solution. Counter-example: `A = [1, 2, 4]`, `B = [3, 5, 1]`, `m = 5`. Answer is `true`, because we can swap `2` with `3`. Your code throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2` on `countB[diff]`, because `diff` is `-2`. Even if you secure it with, for example `diff = Math.abs(sumA - sumB)`, the algorithm is still not correct and it will return `false`.
3. You don't need to do `Arrays.fill(p, 0)`, `int` default value is `0`.
4. Instead of `p[X[i]] += 1` you could write `p[X[i]]++`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will use the codility solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's (i hope) a correct solution.
Please note, that counting can still be put after checking dif is not an odd number to make performance higher.
Note, too,  that listA and listB arrays are used as the value at zero place is never used. This is for better understanding, too. We don't need the occurrence of the value 0 but we need the occurrence of max value.

```
public boolean solution(int[] A, int[] B, int max) {
    int[] listA = new int[max+1];
    int[] listB = new int[max+1];
    int listAsum =0;
    int listBsum=0;

    for(int i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
        listA[A[i]]++;
        listAsum +=A[i];
        listBsum +=B[i];
    }
    int diff = listAsum - listBsum;
    if(diff%2 == 1) return false;
    diff /=2;
    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        if((B[i] - diff) >= 0  && (B[i]-diff) <= max && listA[(B[i]-diff)] > 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean solution(int[] A, int[] B, int max) {
    int[] count = new int[max + 1];//count(A, max);
    int sum_a = 0; //Arrays.stream(A).sum();
    int sum_b = 0;//Arrays.stream(B).sum();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        count[A[i]]++;
        sum_a += A[i];
        sum_b += B[i];
    }
    int d = sum_b - sum_a;
    if (d % 2 == 1) return false;
    d /= 2;


    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if ((B[i] - d) >= 0 && (B[i] - d) <= max && count[(B[i] - d)]    > 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public int[] count(int[] X, int max) {
    int[] p = new int[max + 1];
    Arrays.fill(p, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        p[X[i]]++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Try to give the reason for the error while answering